# Question marked as duplicate is not a duplicate and the original question is deleted. Can someone review?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

So while looking at this recent question:

- [Accessing a bridged modem from behind a router](https://superuser.com/questions/971414/accessing-a-bridged-modem-from-behind-a-router)

The poster states:

> There is [an existing question](https://superuser.com/questions/841589/accessing-modem-setting-via-router) that seems quite similar; however,
>   it was marked as a duplicate of a question that no longer appears to
>   exist, so there is no longer an answer to that question.

Okay, so that sounded weird. Since the screenshots below will make this hard to read, here is the long and short of it:

I believe the deleted question should not have been deleted or closed. And I believe the supposed dupe should not have been marked as a dupe.  They are 100% two different questions. One is about [connecting to a modem via a router](https://superuser.com/questions/841589/accessing-modem-settings-via-router-on-a-lan) and the other is about [connecting to a laptop’s `localhost:8080` via a router](https://superuser.com/questions/841586/connecting-to-localhost8080-on-my-laptop-from-android).

The worst error both questions suffered from were formatting quirks and typos in IP addresses like `192.168.1` instead of `192.168.1.1`. And perhaps those IP address lists looked the same which caused inadvertent flagging of “dupe.” But that’s it.

Can someone with more power than me please review these two questions? Maybe they aren’t great, but they don’t seem invalid. Screenshots and links below.

---

## Marked as a duplicate question.

This is [the question that was marked as a dupe](https://superuser.com/questions/841589/accessing-modem-settings-via-router-on-a-lan):

[image]

## Deleted original question.

This is [the supposed original which the later was a dupe of](https://superuser.com/questions/841586/connecting-to-localhost8080-on-my-laptop-from-android):

[image]

Comment: hmm. 2 questions by the same user, with identical content. I'd be inclined to nuke both, so the next time someone asks the same question better, we'd not close them as a dupe of this.

Comment: @JakeGould Your last edit to the closed dupe doesn't help. I took one look at the closed question and thought leave it closed as your edit has the PC **and** the phone on the **same IP address**. This makes any answers completely different as it then looks like a duplicate IP address issue needing to be be fixed. The original question had **different IP addresses**. If you want people to vote to undelete/reopen you need to be more careful with your edits.

Comment: Look at [the first revision](http://superuser.com/revisions/da3a306d-47c8-45df-8649-7f5e4a5528d7/view-source) of the «Accessing modem settings …» question. It started as a nearly exact copy of the «Connecting to “localhost:8080” on my Laptop from Android» question, complete with all the bits about Android, which weren’t removed until after the newer question (by a margin of ***16 minutes!***) got closed as a dup. And I [voted](http://superuser.com/review/reopen/428260) to leave it closed because it’s unclear. What brand(s) of equipment? What commands tried, and what error messages received?